# Semantic UI popup is only hidden once

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I try to show a popup on click event for a given duration before to hide it. This work fine only once. When I click a second time I got this unexpected behaviour, the popup does not hide anymore. Any idea?

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('.button').popup({
    on: 'manual',
    inline: true
  }).popup('show').delay(500).queue(() => {
    $('.button').popup("hide")
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div id="smile" class="ui button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me first</div>
<div class="ui popup">You can see this disappear only once</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `setTimeout`

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('.button').popup({
    on: 'manual',
    inline: true
  }).popup('show')
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.button').popup("hide")
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div id="smile" class="ui button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me first</div>
<div class="ui popup">You can see this disappear everytime</div>
```